# index.php script wont load?

Tags: php, database, content-management-system

The cms won't load, it will only show a blanc page under the name of index.php. It worked fine before I added the foreach loop. I looked up on the internet and I couldn't find anything wrong with the foreach loop. It suddenly didn't work anymore. Help? :-)
Below here are the files I am currently using.

**INDEX.PHP**

```
  include_once('includes/connection.php');
  include_once('includes/article.php');

  $article = New Article;
  $articles = $article->fetch_all();

  print_r($articles);
?>

  <html>
    <head>
      <title>Visuality dashboard</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/stylesheet.css">
    </head>

    <body>
      <div class="container">
        <a href="index.php" id="logo">CMS</a>
       <ol>
          <?php foreach ($articles as $article) { ?>
            <li>
              <a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $article ['article_id']; ?>">
                <?php echo $article['article_title']; ?>
              </a>
              - <small>
                posted <?php echo date('l jS, $article['article_timestamp']');?>
              </small>
            </li>

          <?php } ?>
      </ol>
    </div>
    </body>

    <footer>
    </footer>
  </html>
```

**ARTICLE.PHP**

```
    <?php

  class Article {
    public function fetch_all() {
      global $pdo;

      $query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM articles");
      $query->execute();

      return $query->fetchAll();
  }
}

?>
```

**CONNECT.PHP**

```
<?php

  try {
  $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=cms', 'root', 'root');
} catch (PDOException $e) {
  exit('Database error.');
}

?>
```

Comment: have you got display errors off? and have you checked your error log?

Comment: Nothing. No red flags or any errors. The code is OK from my point of view (no color erros either), but the index.php won't load at all, just a blanc page.

Comment: @AyrtonFurtadoMartins: "red flags", "color errors"?  Have you looked at the actual PHP error logs?  My guess is there's a syntax error, the code highlighting on Stack Overflow even shows you where it is.

Comment: Display errors seems to be off. Else you would get at least a `syntax error`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change following:

```
<a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $article ['article_id']; ?>">
```

to

```
<a href="article.php?id=<?php echo $article['article_id']; ?>">
```

and

```
posted <?php echo date('l jS, $article['article_timestamp']');?>
```

to

```
posted <?php echo date('l jS', $article['article_timestamp']);?>
```

Comment: You are welcome! I would suggest you an editor with a good syntax highlighting so you immediately figure out such "typos".